# Javascript find() method not working for nested object/array/json values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to figure out why the nested `find()` method is not working. Here is my data structure

```
const arr = [
    {id: 1, name: "one"},
    {id: 2, name: "two"},
    {id: 3, name: "three"},
    {id2: [
        {id3: 30, name: "thirty"},
        {id3: 50, name: "fifty"},
        {id3: 70, name: "seventy"}
        ]
    }
]
```

The idea is to access the `id3` values for which I am using the nested `find()` method like this:

```
const ret = arr.find(function(el){
    return el.id2.find(function(elps){
        return elps
    })
})
```

Interestingly, I am intermittently getting two different errors.

1. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

OR I get

2. `find is not a function...`

I also tried using `some()` method for the second iteration but it returns the same errors.

If I use `find()` on the parent level(1st iteration) array it works fine like this:

```
const ret = arr.find(function(el){
        return el.id > 2
})
```

**My question:** What is that I am missing in second iteration that the `find()` method is not working there?

Comment: What exactly is your desired result?

Comment: Not all of the objects in your array have an "id2" property, so that's where the `undefined` error is coming from. The `.find()` function called inside the outer `.find()` will return `true` for all the objects in the "id2" array, so it really doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Array.isArray()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) before implementing the nested `find()` to avoid using it on an undefined property or property where value isn't an array

It's not really clear what your expected result is so the following returns the main array object that contains a matching sub-array element

```js
const arr = [
    {id: 1, name: "one"},
    {id: 2, name: "two"},
    {id: 3, name: "three"},
    {id2: [
        {id3: 30, name: "thirty"},
        {id3: 50, name: "fifty"},
        {id3: 70, name: "seventy"}
        ]
    }
]

const res = arr.find(({id2}) => Array.isArray(id2) && id2.find(({id3}) => id3 === 30))
console.log(res)
```